# Error: IEnumerable<CommonViewModel>' does not contain a definition for '<Propertyof Modelclass>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a commonViewModel which contains a List of other models.
i am not able to refer the List of models which are in commonViewModel  in my View through foreach, 
Really appreciate your help!
Here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.ViewModels.Models.CommonViewModel>

<h2>All types of questions asked here</h2>

@foreach (var Mylist in Model.Question1)
{
<li>@Mylist.Question1</li>
}
```

commonViewModel class looks like below

```
public class CommonViewModel
{
    public List<Question> Question1 {get; set;}
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItem { get; set; }

}
```

Question Class looks like below:

```
public partial class Question
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string question1 { get; set; }
}
```

Error: Model.Question1 in View is not identified.

Error   CS1061  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Question1' and no extension method 'Question1' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you show us How Method in Controller looks like? And Question class also. Because you are trying to Get value Property Question1 from Queston1 Property of CommonViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

Your view model is an `IEnumerable<CommonViewModel>`, which in turn has a property `Question1`.

So you can't directly iterate over `Model.Question1`, because `Model` is `IEnumerable<CommonViewModel>`.

So you'll need to loop twice:

```
foreach (var viewModel in Model)
{
    foreach (var question in viewModel.Question1)
    {
        <li>@question.WhatEver</li>
    }
}
```